# Pygame: Why the code never reaches the second print?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a litle game with pygame where a ship doges asteroids and I wanted to use a boolean as an anticolision device, what I mean is anticolision will be always false except if there is a colision, then it should be True a not allow for any collisions to happen, after 1 second anticolision will return back to False. The idea is to avoid the explosion animation and the life loss while there is already an animation going on. I think the logic is correct but I can't seem to make it work. I always get the first print, but not the second. The weird thing is that it works correctly in vsc debugger, but that's the only way I can reach that second print and the change of the value back to normal. Why?

```
current_time = 0
        while running :
#[...]
            current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 
#[...]
            if self.player.estado == self.player.Estado.volando:
                            #comprobar colisión
                
                colisiones = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.asteroides, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
                anticolision = False
                for colision in colisiones:
                    
                    if colision and not anticolision:
                        anticolision_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                        anticolision = True 
                        print("anticolision true")                        
                        expl = Explosion(colision.rect.center)
                        self.explosionSound.play()
                        self.all_sprites.add(expl)                  
                        self.vidas -= 1
                        espera = (anticolision_time - current_time)/ 1000
                        if espera > 1:
                            print("anticolision false")
                            anticolision = False
                                
                    else:
                        pass

                    if self.vidas == 0:     
                        self.gameOver()
                        running= False
```

Comment: The code is not waiting for a 1000ms to pass. So `espera >1000` is never satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

I would add `print` statements above your `if` test, so see what the value of `espera` is.

The solution is to make it:
`(anticolision_time - current_time )/ 1000`

to make it work, because the anticolision_time  is going to be larger :) Best of luck!

```
>>> import time
>>> current = time.time()
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> anti_time = time.time()
>>>
>>> current - anti_time
-5.687999963760376
```

as you can see, your variable `current_time` is a bit misleading, you need to rename it to `start_time` to make it clearer

Comment: I still have the same problem, works perfectly fine while debugging, but it doesn't works while running. I made the print(espera) above the If statement and although while debugging works fine while running only prints "0.0"